# How to fix "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.- Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'

Tags: java, react-native

I'm new in react-native and this is my first app. I followed the steps [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started).but once  I run the command react-native run-android

this error appeared

> Starting JS server... Building and installing the app on the device
>   (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details. Make sure you have an
>     Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your
>     Android development environment:
>     [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

Here is my JAVA_HOME variable and my ANDRIOD_HOME variable 
[Click here please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMpUb.png)

Please note that I run the app on a device connected not on Android emulator
I'm using "windows OS", "android mobile" and my gradle version is 4.4

Also I went to my android dir and made a file names local.properties and put into it this path

> sdk.dir=C:\Users\Eman Fateen\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

---

Could you please help me how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't build with a version of Gradle that doesn't support JDK 11.0.1 itself. Either:

1. you can either edit the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file to select a different distribution  OR

   2. use a Gradle >= 4.7 version to run the wrapper update task.

If neither of those work then you could try downgrading the **JDK** like [this](https://service.uoregon.edu/TDClient/KB/ArticleDet?ID=32227).

Comment: I agree, I was having this same problem last night with LibGDX. I downloaded Java 8 and changed my path and it worked after a couple of trial and error and reboots.